# Gap between the words in Key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dictionary, angularjs-ng-repeat

Let us suppose there is a gap between the words of the key. For example

```
<div ng-app="">
     <div ng-init="language=[{'language': 'Python', 'Web Framework': 'Django'},
        {'language': 'PHP','Web Framework': 'Laravel'}]">
     </div>
     <p ng-repeat="lang in language">
        Language: {{lang.language}} <br>
        Web Framework: {{lang.Web Framework}}<br>
     </p>
  </div>
```

How to get {{lang.Web Framework}}. I know, i am going wrong there should not be gap between the words, but suppose i get the requirement then how i gonna do it.

Comment: Basic object accessing question. Should have done searching before posting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as

```
  Web Framework: {{lang["Web Framework"]}}<br>
```

**DEMO**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="">
     <div ng-init="language=[{'language': 'Python', 'Web Framework': 'Django'},
        {'language': 'PHP','Web Framework': 'Laravel'}]">
     </div>
     <p ng-repeat="lang in language">
        Language: {{lang.language}} <br>
        Web Framework: {{lang["Web Framework"]}}<br>
     </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted! ***** reason

Comment: Yaa, I got it. This was really silly. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: mark if that helped